# PL/SQL - If statement to check salary

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm attempting to develop a program that takes a number from the user, sorts employees by their highest salary, and displays a number of rows equivalent to the input number showing the top earners. The program should also verify if the last employee received the same salary as the next employee. If this is the case, the next employee should also be displayed.

I have attempted to modify the code, but none of my changes seem to be effective. Do you have any suggestions for how to make the code operate in accordance with the description provided? The functional code is included below.

Thank you.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p5_q5 (num_employee NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
  FOR emp IN (SELECT ENAME, SAL
              FROM EMP
              ORDER BY SAL DESC
              FETCH FIRST num_employee ROWS ONLY) -- Will be returned X rows according to input of the user (num_employee)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || emp.ENAME || ' - Salary: ' || emp.SAL);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

EXEC p5_q5(3);
```

*Output:

Employee name: KING - Salary: 5512.5
Employee name: JONES - Salary: 3570
Employee name: SCOTT - Salary: 3450

*Ideal Output:

Employee name: KING - Salary: 5512.5
Employee name: JONES - Salary: 3570
Employee name: SCOTT - Salary: 3450
Employee name: FORD - Salary: 3450

I have tried several strategies, but have been unsuccessful in developing a method to determine if the subsequent employee earns the same salary as the previous employee, and to display that employee if they do earn the same amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS WITH TIES`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p5_q5 (num_employee NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
  FOR emp IN (SELECT ENAME, SAL
              FROM EMP
              ORDER BY SAL DESC
              FETCH FIRST num_employee ROWS WITH TIES)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || emp.ENAME || ' - Salary: ' || emp.SAL);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp (ename, sal) AS
  SELECT 'Alice', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Betty', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carol',  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Debra',  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Emily',  90 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  p5_q5(1);
END;
/
```

and

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  p5_q5(2);
END;
/
```

Both output:

> ```
> Employee name: Alice - Salary: 100
> Employee name: Betty - Salary: 100
> ```

and:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  p5_q5(3);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Employee name: Alice - Salary: 100
> Employee name: Betty - Salary: 100
> Employee name: Carol - Salary: 90
> Employee name: Debra - Salary: 90
> Employee name: Emily - Salary: 90
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CxSi_Bkf)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p5_q5 (num_employee NUMBER) AS
curr_salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
curr_salary := 0;
FOR emp IN (SELECT ENAME, SAL
FROM EMP
ORDER BY SAL DESC)
LOOP
IF emp.SAL = curr_salary THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || emp.ENAME || ' - Salary: ' || emp.SAL);
num_employee := num_employee - 1;
ELSE
curr_salary := emp.SAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || emp.ENAME || ' - Salary: ' || emp.SAL);
num_employee := num_employee - 1;
END IF;
IF num_employee = 0 THEN
  EXIT;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/

EXEC p5_q5(3);
```